Regarding RestRequest headers
I am trying to set the RestRequest reqeust with the below code, however up on pushing to org I am getting an error.
Code:
  private static void setAuthHeader(RestRequest req, Boolean mockTest) {
    String token = 'Bearer ' + TelecomsApiTokenHelper.getAccessToken(mockTest);
    req.addHeader('Authorization', token);
  }

Error: System.InvalidHeaderException: Header name "Authorization" is not allowed.
Any feedback would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Dan

authorization isn't supported: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_addHeader

@willard - you should post this as the answer

Authorization isn't supported: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_addHeader
